# WCF, adding field in communication- how to do it?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, soap, datacontract

I derieved from my friend WCF application with exposed webservices. Communication is over SOAP (xml). It is working,but I can't add field to this protocol.  I mean that I would like to add a field (String field) to the class and be able to send it in xml.

I added this to the class:
`string someField`
In the XML file I also added (next to other elements corresponding this class) this field with value (analogously to other string fields).

However, after deserializing this fields is `null`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share some code. Specifically model definition.

Comment: At this moment, I do not have access to this code. My question is more or less theoretical. But in spring it is simple - it works in way as I described (spring + JSON)

Comment: If you said that you added a `String` to the class, then you have access to the code. Do you not?

Comment: I have, but now I am at home (code is in my work)

Comment: It is just as equally easy in WCF. Without seeing your code (specifically annotations) I don't think anyone will be able to help you. I've done it in both Java and C# and there is no real difference in how it works

Comment: So, tell me what annotation should be above this class ?

Comment: Here you go: https://wcfdataannotations.codeplex.com/

Comment: My doubts are about:     `[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.devtrends.co.uk/example/data")]`. What does it mean? WSDL file is crucial ?

Comment: If you don't provide your own namespace then the WSDL will use default. But since you already have a contract and a working service you probably shouldn't modify it.

Comment: in the filepath there is present some wsdl file, however I am not sure if it is used. Try to help me, I first once work with webservices. Of course, I read some stuff, but work in ready code is fairly hard. Maybe could you tell me what should I do?

Comment: I thought you said you did it with `Spring`? Anyway, this is not the place for a WCF tutorial. Google it or use StackOverflow Documentation section: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wcf/topics